# Trying to make menu items pink when viewing their div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of links that make divs slide in above them, which I made using a script I found here: http://flesler.blogspot.ca/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html.

I want the link to change color when they are clicked, so that the user can clearly see where they are. I would like to do something like:

```
<li><a href="#promo" onclick="this.style.color='green'; return false;">Promo Package</a></li>
```

Except that changes the color back to its original color when another link is clicked. Also of course external would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a click listener on the list:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('ul a').css('color', '#000000'); // set all links to black;
    $(this).css('color', '#00FF00'); // set curent link to green;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @user1466859 You haven't post your code ("the following" what?), but it sure works on its own. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wwGFB/

Comment: I got it to work! Awesome, thanks alot everyone! (I still don't get what `code` means though lol)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a CSS style instead ?

if you have jQuery :

```
<li><a href="#promo" class="link_black">Promo Package</a></li>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.link_black').click(function(){
        jQuery(".link_green").removeClass('link_green');
        jQuery(this).addClass('link_green');
    });
});


<style>
.link_black{
    color : black;
}
a.link_black{
    color : green;
}
</style>
```

if you do not use jQuery :

```
<li><a href="#promo" class="link_black" onclick="clickedGreenLink(this)">Promo Package</a></li>

<script>
function clickedGreenLink(obj){
   if (window.currentGreenLink!=undefined){
      window.currentGreenLink.class=window.currentGreenLink.class.replace('link_green','');
   }
   window.currentGreenLink=obj;
   window.currentGreenLink.class+='link_green';
}
</script>
```

That should work

Comment: Where can I find how to format my comments? I want to post code but `code` doesn't make sense to me. I have tried two of your guy's suggestions but can't get it to work. thanks!